# Requesting Resource from SAML2 Identity Provider Post-Login

Tags: asp.net, security, saml

Scenario:
I work on a portal application that has its own user credential store. Another company who has a mobile app needs to authenticate against our data store using SAML 2.0.

The user will launch the mobile app, it will send an authentication request to the portal/IdP, the portal presents login page, user logs in and a SAML response is then sent back so user can continue using mobile app.

My question: Is there anything else extra needed if a user clicks a link in the mobile app that requests a protected page on the portal? I mean, the user will be authenticated in the portal already, so it should let them right in without any other kind of token or whatever sent to the portal from the mobile browser - is that right?

Are there any other considerations or resources for referencing a situation like this?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects that needs to be considered here: Authentication and Authorization. Even though the user is authenticated, s/he might not be authorized (i.e. have permissions) to access that particular link.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow SAML 2.0 protocol that is OK.
You have just to be careful what are you sending with AuthetnicationResponse and how it will be used on mobile app.
There is not extra tokens. AuthenticationResponse (encrypted and signed) is token by itself.